# Email this webpage via google apps (for domains) from Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, autohotkey, google-workspace, bookmarklet, email-integration

Does anyone know of an easy way to email the link to a webpage in Google Chrome?

Ideally, the method would take the title of the page and put it in the subject field, put the URL at the top of the body, and, if any text on the page is selected, put that text in the body field as well. It would also have a user-assignable keyboard shortcut (e.g. Ctrl+Alt+A). This is the behavior of the [EmailThis addon for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3102/), which is fantastic, but I haven't found an equivalent for Chrome. ([Email this page](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/dbeoemfhkdniadbojeencpkgmobndpai) only works with Gmail, not Google Apps.)

A Chrome extension would be the most obvious choice, but I could see a bookmarklet or [AutoHotKey](http://AutoHotKey.com) script being of use.

It looks like the URL parameters aren't too difficult:
https://mail.google.com/a/DOMAIN/?view=cm&tf=1&to=&su=SUBJECT&body=BODY&fs=1

Now how about some javascript or AutoHotKey script for getting the URL, title, and selected
text in order to fill on those parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Send from Gmail (by Google)](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/pgphcomnlaojlmmcjmiddhdapjpbgeoc). In the Options, you can set the Google Apps domain.

If you want both apps and gmail, you can install the Email this page extension mentioned in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

How about this bookmarklet:

javascript:popw='';Q='';x=document;y=window;if(x.selection) {Q=x.selection.createRange().text;} else if (y.getSelection) {Q=y.getSelection();} else if (x.getSelection) {Q=x.getSelection();}popw = y.open('http://mail.google.com/a/vbrad.com/?view=cm&fs=1&tf=1&to=&su=' + escape(document.title) + '&body=' + escape(Q) + escape('\n') + escape(location.href) + '&zx=RANDOMCRAP&shva=1&disablechatbrowsercheck=1&ui=1','gmailForm','scrollbars=yes,width=680,height=510,top=175,left=75,status=no,resizable=yes');if (!document.all) T = setTimeout('popw.focus()',50);void(0);

Replace YOURDOMAIN with, well, your domain

Answer (score -1):

How about the "Email this page" extension:

https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/dbeoemfhkdniadbojeencpkgmobndpai

Comment: Thanks, but apparently you did not read the question in its entirety - "Email this page only works with Gmail, not Google Apps.".

Comment: Yes, but perhaps you could leave the extension set on the default mail client instead of GMail, and then set your default mail client preference in your OS to Google Apps via the instructions here: http://bnee.com/2008/09/make-mailto-links-open-in-gmail-in-google-chrome-browser-windows-xp-and-vista/

Comment: P.S. - You'll have to scroll down to the bottom of the article to find the Google Apps part.